# How to use gettext() with dynamic message id as an argument in C

Tags: c, gettext

I want to know how to use gettext in C with dynamic message id in the argument.

For example,

```
char *var = fun();   //where fun returns char * type.

char *val = gettext(var);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is fine, but you will of course also need to make sure that `fun()` returns a static string, that's going to stick around. Also `val` should be `const char *`, you cannot change the strings owned by gettext.